# gawk behaviour I don't understand

Tags: awk, gawk

I am trying to count the number of distinct values in field 12 of a file using gawk 4.1.4, and also count the number of times each of those values occurs. I have two short programs which are giving me different answers for the first question, and I am at a loss to explain why.

```
{if(a[$12]++==1){count++}} END {print count}
```

...gives a result of 435,176, whereas

```
{a[$12]++} END {for (i in a){count++};print count}
```

...gives a result of 599,845.

Can you explain this behaviour, and tell me which value is correct? I am running under Windows (ezwinport) and the field separator is tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is wrong (logically, not syntactically, thank you for emphasizing the fact, @GeorgeVasiliou), because you need to `++` before `==`: `++a[$1]==1` :

```
$ awk '{if(++a[$1]==1){count++}} END {print count}' foo
3
```

Oh yeah, my test `foo`:

```
$ cat foo
1
1
1
2
2
3
```

Comment: Yes, or can use `{if(a[$12]++==0){count++}} END {print count}` but I feel that's slightly harder-to-grok code.

Comment: Good stuff! My only problem with this is, `count` is not needed, you have the array value itself to make it work!

Comment: @Inian Tru dat. Since gawk (lol) was mentioned in the OP, one could get the number of distinct values with `length()`: `{a[$1]++} END {print length(a)}`, right?

Comment: It seems like that works too. I wasn't aware you could use `length` on an array in this way, thanks.

Comment: The first one used by OP is wrong in terms of specific programming logic but not wrong in terms of syntax. The syntax `if(a[$12]++==1){count++}` will increase `count` by 1 every time that `$12` is found exactly two times. This is because of the post increment - `a[$12]` is first evaluated by if and then increased with `++` operation.

Comment: Yep, this correctly describes the bug in my first example snippet, I needed to use pre- and not post-fix `++`. The `length` example above is more succinct, however.

Comment: if you wanna just count distinct, then why bother to even increment the de-duping array ?  :::::::::::: just `awk 'END { print length(_) } _[$!__]'` more than suffices

Comment: Well, that wasn't the point of the answer, which was to fix OP's code. Also, `print length(_)` won't cut it in all awks, for example mawk.

Answer (score 2):

> Obviously the *2nd* one seems right!
>   You already have the `count` stored and you don't need a separate variable

The way you are using the `count` to identify the unique occurrence is wrong in both the cases in the sense it is *not* tracked per unique instance.

Use the value from the array itself.

The logic in deriving `count`

```
{if(a[$12]++==1){count++}} END {print count}
```

is *wrong*, but the fact what it does is with post-increment operator *only* when a field in `$12` occurs for the second time it is tracked in the `count` variable. Hence the *lesser* count you are seeing in your output.

On the other hand,

```
{a[$12]++} END {for (i in a){count++};print count}
```

is almost right, but you don't need a `count` variable, you already have it stored as part of the value in the array `a`, indexed by the unique value `$12`. Doing the above is also the same as

```
{a[$12}++; next} END {for (i in a) print a[i]}
```

A small example to demonstrate it,

```
cat file
1 2 3
1 2 3
1 2 1
1 1 1
2 3 1
3 4 1
```

assuming I am worried about unique instances and their occurrence count in `$2`. Doing your first example,

```
awk '{if(a[$2]++==1){count++}}END {for (i in a) print i,a[i],count}' file
1 1 1
2 3 1
3 1 1
4 1 1
```

see the wrong value of `count` printed in the last column, if you can see it carefully, the variable is not even keep tracking the count *per instance*  but a common variable for all instances.

The second approach, *seemingly* looks good, but prints `count` as `4` not clear for which instance, assuming *multiple* instances and their counts could possibly occur. The right way would be to do,

```
awk '{a[$2]++; next}END {for (i in a) print i,a[i]}' file
1 1
2 3
3 1
4 1
```

Here instead of `count`, the `a[i]` holds the unique count occurrence of the each of the unique value from the column 2.

Comment: The purpose of both the snippets was to simply count the number of unique values, whilst summing the counts of each value but not printing them.

Comment: @MattWenham: Fair enough, don't print them, just use the array value.